# How to extract a specific node from a XML & create new xml using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

The acutal xml is:

```
<prnReq>
    <ltrPrnReqs>
        <ltrPrnReq>
            <ltrData>
                <Postal>910060121</Postal>
                <Amt>514.17</Amt>
            </ltrData>
        </ltrPrnReq>
    </ltrPrnReqs>
</prnReq>
```

The final XML must be only the 'ltrData':

```
      <ltrData>
            <Postal>910060121</Postal>
            <Amt>514.17</Amt>
      </ltrData>
```

Below the current code, where I need to create a new file using only the  tag, however, the code is not running.

```
import groovy.xml.QName
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def xmlString = """
<prnReq>
    <ltrPrnReqs>
          <ltrPrnReq>
             <ltrData>
                <Postal>910060121</Postal>
                <Amt>514.17</Amt>
            </ltrData>
          </ltrPrnReq>
    </ltrPrnReqs> 
</prnReq>"""


def xml1 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString) 
def ltrD = xml1.'**'.find{it.name() == 'ltrData'}.text()

def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
builder.encoding = 'UTF-8'
def xml2 = builder.bindNode (ltrD)

def file1 = new File('C:\\Temp\\out\\ltrData.xml')
assert XmlUtil.serialize(xml2)
file1.write(xml2,'UTF-8'))
```

Hi @Rao, I've just updated the  content. When I try to apply the proposed solution I got an error: "[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.". 
So I believe I'm still doing something wrong getting the  content. Could you please have a look how to get the correct syntax to get both new elements above? Many thanks

Comment: Raul, please check the answer to see if that is helpful

Comment: Hi I would suggest you to edit question instead of answer.

Comment: Just saw that, you have changed  structure of xml. Actually do you need to extract any data from exist xml and want that to use in new xml?

Comment: Hi @Rao, yes, I do need only the 'ltrData' content in a new XML file.

Comment: It seems that there is no need to refer to the existing xml then. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer, can you please try it and see if that is what you needed?

Comment: Hi @Rao, I've updated the code above, took off all the old content. Now the code just needs to get the 'ltrData' content to the new XML file. Sorry my previous mess.
I'm trying to apply the method 'bindNode' to get the content there, however I'm getting the error: "[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog."

Comment: Raul, can I request you to first the try the given solution below and see what is happening?

Comment: Hi @Rao, I've been playing for a while with your suggested class "StreamingMarkupBuilder". What I need to extract is a node from the original XML. I've included in the sample just 2 fields but I do have a lot of them under 'ltrData', including some array there. In this way, I've been looking for a method there that can receive a node as a parameter, however, I can't find the correct syntax for it. If you do have any idea it will be really welcome. Many thanks

Comment: When I ask you what data you in the 3 rd comment, you replied `ltrData`, thought only element. Never mind, please show some example what data needs to be extracted from input xml and how it needs to be presented in the output.

Comment: Sorry about that... the whole xml sample is: 
<prnReq>
    <ltrPrnReqs>
          <ltrPrnReq>
             <ltrData>
                <Postal>910060121</PostalAcc>
                <Amt>514.17</Amt>
            </ltrData>
          </ltrPrnReq>
    </ltrPrnReqs> 
</prnReq>
, and in a new XML file I need only what is inside <ltrData>, according to the sample in the question, I will need:
             <ltrData>
                <Postal>910060121</PostalAcc>
                <Amt>514.17</Amt>
            </ltrData>
, hope this makes sense. Thanks @Rao

Comment: Raul, just updated the answer, please check it now to see if that is what you wanted.

Comment: Hi @Rao, thats really good, many thanks. I'm working to have this solution fine on my code and I'll gonna update the post soon.

Comment: Appreciate if you can accept it [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Raul, glad to know that it has helped. You may look at the edit part of the solution which is optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it with `StreamingMarkupBuilder`. And follow the in-line comments:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
def xmlString = """<prnReq> 
  <ltrPrnReqs>
     <ltrPrnReq>
        <ltrData>
           <Postal>910060121</Postal>
           <Amt>514.17</Amt>
        </ltrData>
     </ltrPrnReq>
   </ltrPrnReqs>
</prnReq>"""

//Extract the data you needed from existing xml
def xml1 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString) 
def ltrData1 = xml1.'**'.find{it.name() == 'ltrData'}
def nodes = ltrData1.children()*.name()

//Build the output xml
def xml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {    
    ltrData { 
       nodes.each { "$it"(ltrData1."$it".text()) }
    }
}
def file = new File('C:/Temp/out/letter_PQC301.xml')
println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
file.write(XmlUtil.serialize(xml),'UTF-8')
​
```

You can quickly try the same online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/dzLUa2)</kbd>

**EDIT:** Optimized solution. Note that below uses without `StreamingMarkupBuilder`

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
def xmlString = """<prnReq> 
  <ltrPrnReqs>
     <ltrPrnReq>
        <ltrData>
           <Postal>910060121</Postal>
           <Amt>514.17</Amt>
        </ltrData>
     </ltrPrnReq>
   </ltrPrnReqs>
</prnReq>"""

//Extract the data you needed from existing xml
def xml1 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString) 
def ltrData1 = xml1.'**'.find{it.name() == 'ltrData'}

def file = new File('C:/Temp/out/letter_PQC301.xml')
println XmlUtil.serialize(ltrData1)
file.write(XmlUtil.serialize(ltrData1),'UTF-8')
```